# How to use SOAP in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap

Dont know what to do.

I have all the data i need but dont know how to use it right.

I have started to add a "Service Reference". I added the URL wich is this one: transpawebserviceslive/gateway.asmx

So what i have done now is this. For my click event on my button to verify that the password and username is correct i have done the following and i dont know if i am doing it right here:

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
  ServiceReference.GatewaySoapClient client = new  ServiceReference.GatewaySoapClient();
  client.AuthenticateAsync(username.Text,password.Text,sign.Text,password.Text);
  client.AuthenticateCompleted += client_AuthenticateCompleted;
  }

  void client_AuthenticateCompleted(object sender,  ServiceReference.AuthenticateCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference.AuthenticatedDto test = new  ServiceReference.AuthenticatedDto();

        if (kund.Text == test.CustomerUser)
        {
            MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Ok", "Ok", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Wrong", "W", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
```

Dont know what i am doing here, whould be nice with some help.

Comment: Anyone have any good tutorial?

Comment: Can anyone just point me in the right direction. What am i missing in the AuthenticateCompleted for example. Give me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you did there is correct. You just have to parse the response and proceed.

```
void client_AuthenticateCompleted(object sender,  ServiceReference.AuthenticateCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null) //To ensure there is no error in the request
        {
            if (e.Result.Contains("ERROR"))
                MessageBox.Show("Authentication failed", "Ok", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Authenticaion success", "Ok", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
}
```